# How to profile the python worker memory of PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an application that use PySpark to extract features, But the application always killed with error.

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 14.4 GB of 14 GB physical memory used.
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

From the Spark Web UI, It always killed at the combineByKey operator.

From the NodeManager's log It shows so many memory used by the python worker process.

But I have never set the memory for python worker. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/configuration.html#runtime-environment) there is a setting `spark.python.worker.memory` which default is 512m, but one python worker process used almost 10g memory, and yarn killed the container.

Why the `spark.python.worker.memory` setting not work?

Can anyone show me some reference for profiling the python worker memory?

Thanks so much.

Comment: can you try setting an upper limit on the worker memory to 75% of the total available on node

Comment: @ChitralVerma I had increased the executor-memory to 28g when submit the application, and the application and go through the `combineByKey` operator. From the top command result, I can see some python worker use many memory. There is indeed key  skew when extract features.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code.